# How to change Linear Layout alignment to centerInParent PROGRAMATICALLY

Tags: android

> I have two Layouts the one Relative Layout the another one is Linear
>   Layout... Relative Layout is a Parent Layout while Linear Layout is a
>   child layout of Relative Layout.... Simply i want to align Linear
>   Layout as layout_centerInParent... it works within xml but i want to
>   change it PROGRAMATICALLY

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hello World"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#CENTER_IN_PARENT) using [addRule()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int,%20int)) method as below:

```
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Then use `setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLay= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
myLay.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Comment: The question is about centering linear layout not the textview

Comment: @Spiderman, By mistake i mentioned for textview. Now check my answer.